# Optimization using NEON intrinsics

Tags: c, arm, simd, neon, intrinsics

I'm very beginner to NEON intrinsic. I am trying to optimize the algorithm below

```
    uint32_t blue = 0, red = 0 , green = 0, alpha = 0, factor = 0 , shift = 0;

    // some initial calculation to calculate factor shift and R G B init values all are expected to be initilized with 16 bit unsigned

    //pSRC is 32 bbp flat pixel array and count is total pixels count

     for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
     {
        blue  += *psrc++;
        green += *psrc++;
        green += *psrc++;
        alpha += *psrc++;

        *pDest++ = static_cast< uint_8 >( ( blue * factor ) >> shift );
        *pDest++ = static_cast< uint_8 >( ( green * factor ) >> shift );
        *pDest++ = static_cast< uint_8 >( ( red * factor ) >> shift );
        *pDest++ = static_cast< uint_8 >( ( alpha * factor ) >> shift );
     }
```

I am not sure how to do this since I need the result in 32-bit containers and I have source data as 8-bit `( R G B A )`, and there is no instruction which can add 8-bits with 32-bits.

Can anyone help me out with this?

I was able to convert them to 32-bits as suggested by Paul's link and do the needful arithmetic. Now I have:

```
           uint32x4_t result1 = vshlq_u32(mult1281, shift);
           uint32x4_t result2 = vshlq_u32(mult1282, shift);
           uint32x4_t result3 = vshlq_u32(mult1283, shift);
           uint32x4_t result4 = vshlq_u32(mult1284, shift);
```

result 1/2/3/4 now contains 32-bits (per channel) RGB channels. How can I now combine result 1/2/3/4 to get 8-bits (per channel) RGB channels and put it back to the destination?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert unsigned char to signed integer by neon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528352/how-to-convert-unsigned-char-to-signed-integer-by-neon)

Comment: I don't understand what this algorithm does. Values (blue, green, red, alpha) will rise all time. *pDst can periodicaly overflowing of 8-bit.

Comment: there is a shift also which is essentially a devide so i don't think it will overflow

Comment: Even with the shift, it's still a continuous accumulation.  The writes are inside the loop, and the accumulators are never reset or decreased, so the output is a continuously growing value.  Also you said `green` twice... you mean `blue`, right?

Comment: yes i meant blue..I agree this is continuous accumulation but we are adding 8 bit number ( *psrc ) to 32 bit number( say red ) initialized with 16 bit ( mentioned in code comment )number so i don't see any problem of overflow unless count is too large or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still haven't understood deep sense of the algorithm, but of course you can optimize it with using NEON:

```
uint32_t blue = 0, red = 0, green = 0, alpha = 0, factor = 0, shift = 0;
// some your initializations.
uint32x4_t bgra = { blue, green, red, alpha };
for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 2)
{
    //load 8 8-bit values and unpack to 16-bit
    uint16x8_t src = vmovl_u8(vld1_u8(psrc + i * 4)); 

    //accumulate low 4 values
    bgra = vaddw_u16(bgra, vget_low_u16(src));
    //get low 4 values of dst
    uint32x4_t lo = vshrq_n_u32(vmulq_u32(bgra, vdupq_n_u32(factor)), shift);

    //accumulate high 4 values
    bgra = vaddw_u16(bgra, vget_high_u16(src));
    //get high 4 values of dst
    uint32x4_t hi = vshrq_n_u32(vmulq_u32(bgra, vdupq_n_u32(factor)), shift);

    //pack 8 32-bit values to 8 8-bit.
    uint8x8_t dst = vmovn_u16(vcombine_u16(vmovn_u32(lo), vmovn_u32(hi)));

    //store result
    vst1_u8(pDest + i * 4, dst);
}
```

Comment: worked like charm thanku so much. small coment you can't use vshrq_n_u32 since it expects const shift i used vshlq_u32